# JS function works on chrome console but not when load from plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have a webpage with a function applaud. When I call it from the console, I get the normal return:

```
applaud(3004,1935);
undefined
```

However, if I use CTG plugins (simple plugin to run a js script), with that code

```
applaud(3004,1935);
```

I get the following error in console:

```
3VM5444:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: applaud is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM5444:1
```

and function isn't working.

Do you know how I can use it?

Thanks.

Comment: To use a JS function defined by the web page, the extension needs to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) but CTG plugins doesn't, which is why you can't access that function. Either find another extension that can do it (userscripts in Tampermonkey can do it) or suggest to the author to add this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a bit outdated, but I can answer this. (I made the extension in question.)

Chrome Extensions by default insert scripts into a webpage in a different context than the rest of the page. This is for security reasons. If you'd like to run code in the context of the webpage, you'd need to use a little workaround.

In the script that the Chrome Extension injects, have that inject a `<script>` tag into the body of the page. Then that script will be loaded and be able to execute the functions like you can in the console.

Here's a demo of code that can do what I'm talking about:

```
//Create a new script element.
var script = document.createElement("script");

//Get the function you want to inject as a string and add it to the script.
script.innerHTML = injection.toString();

//Add a call to that injection function so it'll automatically execute once it's injected.
script.innerHTML += "injection();";

//Inject that newly created script into the body of the page.
document.body.appendChild(script);

//The contents of this script will be run inside the same context as the webpage.
function injection(){
    applaud(3004, 1935);
}
```